# MonoTouch: Sending / Receiving NSData Though GameKit

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, nsdata, gamekit

I am trying to implement matchmaking in my MonoTouch game. I have successfully implemented the system to connect players through GameKit, but I am stuck on sending and receiving data.

How would I convert this objective-c code into c#? The type of data I would like to send is a `Vector2` class with `X` and `Y` float components.

```
NSError *error;
PositionPacket msg;
msg.messageKind = PositionMessage;
msg.x = currentPosition.x;
msg.y = currentPosition.y;
NSData *packet = [NSData dataWithBytes:&msg length:sizeof(PositionPacket)];
[match sendDataToAllPlayers: packet withDataMode: GKMatchSendDataUnreliable error:&error];

if (error != nil)
{
    // handle the error
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The *common* way, since `OpenTK.Vector2` is decorated with `[Serializable]`, would be to serialize the structure to a `Stream` (e.g. a `MemoryStream`) then initialize a new `NSData` from it, e.g. using `NSData.FromStream`. There's quite a bit of overhead in doing so but it will work on any structure.

A better use of the `Stream` would be to write your values into it (e.g. with a `StreamWriter`). This removes the serialization overhead (reflection) and allow you to build the stream from different values (without creating a structure).

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream ();
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter (ms)) {
    sw.Write (v2.X);
    sw.Write (v2.Y);
}
ms.Position = 0;
var data = NSData.FromStream (ms);
```

A more *complex* (but potentially **faster** way) is to uses `unsafe` code and `NSData.FromBytes` which accept an `IntPtr` (a pointer) and the size of your data. If all your data is already inside a structure then it's very easy to do.

The *hacky* way is to convert `Vector2` to a type known in `monotouch.dll`, e.g. `PointF`. That will allow you to use `NSData.FromObject`. This API works on `NSObject`, the most basic value-types and some basic types supported by `NSValue` or added inside `monotouch.dll`, e.g. `RectangleF`, `PointF`, ...

```
var v2 = new OpenTK.Vector2 ();
var pt = new System.Drawing.PointF (v2.X, v2.Y);
var data = NSData.FromObject (pt);
```

Comment: Great, thank you for the in depth response! The memory stream seems like the best way for me to send data in this case. On the receiving side, how would I convert the `NSData` back into a `Vector2`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think I figured it out for the most part. For anyone interested, here is my solution.

```
unsafe
{
    NSError error = new NSError((NSString)"Test", 0);

    System.IntPtr pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(PointF));

    PointF packedData = new PointF(position.X, position.Y);

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(packedData, pointer, false);

    NSData packet = NSData.FromBytes(pointer, (uint)sizeof(PointF));

    currentMatch.SendDataToAllPlayers(packet, GKMatchSendDataMode.Unreliable, error.ClassHandle);

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pointer);
}
```

So I'm still not sure what the `NSError` should be, although for my project failed packets don't really matter. Here is the code for receiving a packet.

```
PointF packedData = (PointF)Marshal.PtrToStructure(data.Bytes, typeof(PointF));

var recievedData = new Vector2(packedData.X, packedData.Y);
```